# Upload files using ajax resulting in significant memory leak (Firefox bug)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, firefox, memory-leaks

I've written a javascript uploader which takes images and uploads them to a server.  I've stripped the code down to the bare minimum I can, but I still get a leak in Firefox, and I can't see why.

The script obtains a list of file objects called `files` from a HTML form and then incrementally runs through that list and uploads each file to a server.

The javascript code is as follows:

```
function UploadFile(file) {

        var form_data = new FormData();                  
        form_data.append('file', file);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'Upload.php', 
            dataType: 'text',  
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,                        
            type: 'post',
            success: function(){

                console.log("SUCCESS!");

                upload_counter = upload_counter + 1;

                UploadFile(files[upload_counter]);  //Self calling function

                form_data = null;   //Clearing form data memory
                file = null;

            },
            error: function(error)
            {
                console.log("ERROR!");
            }

 });
}
```

The function is started again by calling itself from within the success function of the AJAX call, this keeps everything linear and simple, note how it increments along to the next index in the `files` array to access the next file object.

The PHP code isn't relevant of course, but suffice to say it handles the upload fine.

Using Windows memory monitor the memory used by Firefox is the following:

- 1 image -> 320Mb
- 10 images -> 500Mb
- 20 images -> 720Mb
- 30 images -> 960Mb
- 40 images -> 1.1Gb
- 140 images -> 1.6Gb
- 150 images -> 1.7Gb

Clearly this is a problem, and eventually Firefox will crash.  The files are quite large (around 10Mb each), so by 150 images around 1.5 Gb's have been uploaded.

Why is it leaking memory?

**I should add**:

- this doesn't happen in **Chrome**, **Edge** or **Opera** their memory doesn't change during upload.
- I have tested this in Firefox safe mode with all add-ons/extensions disabled as well.

As a result of the fact that it only occurs in Firefox, I've submitted a bug here:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1302657

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me days to stumble on this answer.

The problem/bug lies entirely with firebug, the commonly used developer tool plugin.  With it disabled, Firefox actually manages the memory fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a theory, but it might be a problem with Firefox not hanlding correctly the recursivity of your ajax calls. Since it keeps uploading files again and again, it might not be freeing the memory until it finishes and if you end up consuming all the memory before that, then it will crash.
I think that it might be worth to try something like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<file.length;i++){
    UploadFile(files[i]);
}
```

And in your UploadFile function, get rid of these 2 lines:

```
upload_counter = upload_counter + 1;
UploadFile(files[upload_counter]);  //Self calling function
```

Since the "for loop" will already take care of iterate through the files, and with that, you will remove the recursivity in your success callback function.

You might be worried because doing it like that will make the file upload completely asynchronous and it might end up consuming more memory, but since most web browsers limit the number of parallel HTTP requests to up to 6 connections, then based on your benchmarks, you will never be using more than 500MB of RAM (assuming that this approach works for you).

Comment: Thanks for the idea, unfortunately I do need the upload to by synchronous (one after the other), but good call and thanks.   I've actually found the problem.